# How do I populate tkinter drop-down box with data retrieved from my SQLite database?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, tkinter

Basically I have a cinema booking system with a database which stores what films are on and at what time date etc.. I have managed to print the contents in the format I wish to use however, I am unsure how to use this data in terms of using a tkinter drop down menu which individually shows the lines shown underneath.

```
import sqlite3 as lite
conn = lite.connect('Logindetails.db')

with conn:

    conn.row_factory = lite.Row
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    title = raw_input("Name of tile: ")

    query = "SELECT * FROM Viewings WHERE Title=?"
    cursor.execute(query, (title,))

    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        data = "%s %s %s %s %s" % (row["Id"], row["Title"], row["Date"], row["Time"], row["Duration"])
        print data
```

That is my code for retrieving the data that its required. Here is its output.

```
Name of tile: Frozen
1 Frozen 06/15 11:35 95
3 Frozen 06/18 11:35 95
4 Frozen 06/30 11:25 95
5 Frozen 07/02 11:45 95
6 Frozen 07/05 12:30 95
```

I have written the foundations of my tkinter project just unsure how to manipulate this data and import it into a drop down box of which each data set can be selected singularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define `movieList` array somewhere in your code  and then append the strings created in for loop to the `movieList` array:

```
movieList = []
...
for row in rows:
        data = "%s %s %s %s %s" % (row["Id"], row["Title"], row["Date"], row["Time"], row["Duration"])
        movieList.append(data)
        print data
```

*(As a side note, you could leave out `row["Id"]` and `row["Duration"]` fields,
as the former is not really important to your users and the latter is redundant)*

Building the drop-down menu is easy then, using `OptionMenu` widget; here is a minimal example with hard-coded values, the `movieList` of yours will be constructed dynamically in the aforementioned `for` loop:

```
from Tkinter import *

movieList = ["1 Frozen 06/15 11:35 95", "3 Frozen 06/18 11:35 95",
        "4 Frozen 06/30 11:25 95", "5 Frozen 07/02 11:45 95",
        "6 Frozen 07/05 12:30 95"]

master = Tk()

option = StringVar(master)
option.set(movieList[0]) # Set the first value to be the default option

w = apply(OptionMenu, (master, option) + tuple(movieList))
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

You can get the the chosen option then by calling `get()` method:

```
option.get()
```

Comment: Hey that's helped me a lot except I'm getting the error that tuple indices must be integers, not str

Comment: I'm getting no errors. Could you provide the data you're operating on? Maybe simple type conversion would do the trick.

Comment: Never mind sory I edited something wrong. This workd great thank you!